# Laravel 4.2 artisan CLI does not work anymore after composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I just ran "composer update" on my production server, and received this error:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
```

When I try any "php artisan" commands, I do not receive any results.

I have tried deleting my composer.lock file and my vendor folder, and ran "composer install" again, but no results.

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
"laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
"bllim/laravalid": "dev-laravel4",
"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0" 

},
"autoload": {
"classmap": [
"app/commands",
"app/controllers",
"app/composers",
"app/models",
"app/database/migrations",
"app/database/seeds",
"app/tests/TestCase.php"
]
},
"scripts": {
"post-install-cmd": [
"php artisan clear-compiled",
"php artisan optimize"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
"php artisan clear-compiled",
"php artisan optimize"
],
"post-create-project-cmd": [
"php artisan key:generate"
]
},
"config": {
"preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

My production server runs PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4.

Comment: Do you have previous version of `composer.lock`? If yes, use it and run `composer install` and make sure it works before running `composer update`

Comment: You've to delete the compiled file in bootstrap directory.

Comment: If you scroll up in the console, you should see the error, could you post it please?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I solved it and add an aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by following steps:

1. remove vendor folder and composer.lock
2. change composer.jason to default
3. run composer install
4. run composer update
5. in the bllim validation folder "converter" to "Converter"
6. run composer update again

Comment: how to change composer.json to default ?