# Laravel - After I ran composer update CLI artisan issue shows up

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

I have made composer update on laravel project latest version, after that no CLI command is working

```
G:\XAMP\htdocs\laraintro>php artisan make:controller ActionController

←[37;41m                                                 ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  [UnexpectedValueException]                     ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\]  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m                                                 ←[39;49m
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718911/laravel-4-2-artisan-cli-does-not-work-anymore-after-composer-update) but it didn't work for me

Comment: `try` is a reserve keyword. try with different controller name

Comment: I think the error is quite self-explanatory: You have defined a route with an unexisting action. Find out which one it is and artisan will work again.

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain it's just a metaphor .. I used **ActionController**

Comment: @Amarnasan how to check that ? I'm new

Comment: You added a line in the app/Http/routes.php file using an action of a controller that doesn't exist. Find out which one (probably, the last you added).

Comment: Checked and nothing wrong with files .. the routing is working probably, by the way, how does that effect creating a new controller by the CLI ?

Comment: @PoulaAdel The "CLI" (artisan) shares the same bootstrapping as the entire framework. So, if the framework would not load because of a basic critical error in the routing, artisan won't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amarnasan is most likely correct.

The impact of a incorrectly defined route has to do on how Laravel is booted. If you have an invalid route, that will mess with the rest of the code.

So, you need to double check that all routes are correctly defined. This means you need to check if the controllers exist and if the methods for each route exists. Take a [look at the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing) to check how routes should be defined.

If all the routes are correctly execute the following command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Try composer dump-autoload

composer dump-autoload won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php).